# React-native android: Can run app by command but cannot run by android studio

Tags: android, react-native

I'm not sure why after i upgraded react native to :

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-native": "^0.63.3",
```

i can run app by command `npx react-native run-android`, but cannot run in android studio (I've tried on emulator and real device, both also cannot). Cannot run as in it got response in android studio, but if i shake device to refresh, it display: `could not connect to development server`.

And i also noticed the steps of generate apk is changed, normal way is clean>build>generate APK, but after i update, i need to change to: delete index.android.bundle file, then clear gradlew etc (step to update index.android.bundle ref link: https://medium.com/@adityasingh_32512/solved-unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-bdc5e3a3d5ff).
Anyone have faced this issue before? any solution for this?

Comment: Can you see the metro bundler starting up or its not just starting in android studio's case

Comment: no, the metro bundler not even started run, i tried start the metro bundler then run in android studio, it also no triggered in metro bundler